# If $A$ is an nxn matrix, $A^H$ is a Hermitian Matrix and $A^{S}$ is a Skew Hermitian, show $A=A^H+A^{S}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an $n\times n$-matrix,  $A^H$ is a Hermitian Matrix and $A^S$ is a Skew Hermitian, show $A=A^H+A^S$.

I am having trouble working with these so far and really cannot find many characteristics except the definitions. A Hermitian is made up of reals on the diagonal and is $A^*=A$. It is skew hermitian iff the diagonal is made up of imaginary numbers and zero and $A^H =\bar A^T$

Comment: Probably the statement is something like: “Every square matrix $A$ is the sum of a hermitian matrix $A_H$ and a skew-hermitian matrix $A_S$”.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question can be answered in a fairly straightforward fashion using the definitions
$$
A^H = \frac 12 (A + A^*)\\
A^S = \frac 12 (A - A^*)
$$

Comment: Why are they products of 1/2?

Comment: Otherwise we would end up with $2A$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is an $n\times n$-matrix,  $A^H$ is a Hermitian Matrix and $A^S$ is a Skew Hermitian, show $A=A^H+A^S$.

$A^H=1/2(A+A*)$

$A^S=1/2(A-A*)$

$A^H+A^S=1/2(A+A*)+1/2(A-A*)$

$=1/2A+1/2A*+1/2A-1/2A*$

$=A$

QED